# Fundamental group of 3-manifold with boundary

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, fundamental-group

Is it true that *any finitely presented group can be realized as fundamental group of compact 3-manifold **with boundary***?

Comment: There's no need to apologize for a stupid question, and this isn't one.

Comment: There is an important idea behind this question.  We know that every finitely presented group is the fundamental group of a two-complex: namely, the *presentation complex*.  Two-complexes are very low-dimensional, so it is reasonable to (try to!) embed them in a three-dimensional space.  Or, equivalently, thicken them up to be three-dimensional.  The various answers below (including my own) do not say why this does not work... In fact, this *does* work in dimension five.  Every finitely presented group *can* be realised as the fundamental group of a compact five-manifold with boundary.

Comment: Dimension four is an interesting story that I'll skip.  Here is an example of a two-complex that does not embed in any three-manifold.  Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices.  Let $L$ be the two-complex with one-skeleton $K_6$ and where all three-cycles are filled in with triangles.   The "vertex links" in $L$ are copies of $K_5$ (famously non-planar).  This, then, is an obstruction to embedding in a three-manifold.

Comment: @SamNead: Thanks very much for mentioning this example! It turns out to be useful for something I'm doing right now. I suppose the easiest way to descibe $L$ is as the 2-skeleton of the 5-simplex.

Comment: @HJRW - Yes.  I did not come to it that way, but that is a much tidier description. I will point out (for my future self, mostly) that L does not need to be the full two-skeleton.  It is enough to fix a vertex $v$ of $K_6$ and only add the triangles meeting $v$.  This is supposed to underline the "local" nature of this obstruction.

Comment: @HJRW However, I do not understand how the *homotopy type* of the two-complex contributes to (controls?) the embedding problem.  After all, if we care about a particular group $G$ then nothing stops us from replacing the presentation complex by a nicer two-complex with the same fundamental group. I would ask this as a question, if I knew what to ask!  (Probably I am supposed to understand Poincaré duality groups, or something?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A couple of extra points.

Any compact 3-manifold with boundary $M$ can be doubled to give a closed 3-manifold $D$.  As $M$ is a retract of $D$, it follows that $\pi_1(M)$ injects into $\pi_1(D)$.  Therefore, any "poison subgroup" (such as the Baumslag--Solitar groups that Autumn mentions above) applies just as well to compact 3-manifolds as closed 3-manifolds.

Other classes of poison subgroups can be constructed from cohomological conditions.  The Kneser--Milnor Theorem implies that any closed, irreducible 3-manifold with infinite fundamental group is aspherical.  It follows that any freely indecomposable infinite group with cohomologial dimension greater than 3 cannot be a subgroup of a closed 3-manifold (and hence of a compact 3-manifold, by the previous paragraph).

EDIT:

Oh, and yet *another* source of poison subgroups comes from Scott's theorem that 3-manifold groups are *coherent*, meaning that every finitely generated subgroup is finitely presented.  This rules out subgroups like $F\times F$ (where $F$ is a free group), which is not coherent.

Comment: Do you know if there is an algorithm to decide if a group of 3-mnfld-with-bry is trivial?

Comment: There is an algorithm to determine if $\pi_1(M)$ is trivial for compact $M$:  If the boundary has a component that is not a sphere, then $M$ will have nontrivial homology.  If the boundary is a union of spheres, then cap them off with balls to get a closed manifold $N$.  Then, by the Poincare conjecture, which we now know, the question is whether or not $N$ is the three-sphere.  You can use Rubinstein's algorithm to recognize the three-sphere to do this.

Comment: A less intelligent but more simple-minded algorithm is just to apply geometrization and deduce that the word problem is (uniformly) solvable in 3-manifold groups. If you know how to solve the word problem then it's easy to tell if a group is trivial.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit how $M$ turns out to be a retract of its double $D$? 

Comment: Maharana, sure.  D = M<sub>1</sub> U M<sub>2</sub>, where  the M<sub>i</sub> are copies of M.  Now the identifications M<sub>i</sub>->M agree on their boundaries, so extend to a map D->M.  This is the retraction.

Comment: The answer by Richard Kent is correct.

Comment: Charlie, I don't think I understand your comment.  Certainly, everything Richard has said is correct.  Are you suggesting that something else isn't correct?

Answer (score 29):

No.  The Baumslag--Solitar groups $\langle a, b | ab^m a^{-1} = b^n \rangle$ are not three-manifold groups when $m \neq n$.

See:

Heil, Wolfgang H. [*Some finitely presented non-$3$-manifold groups*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-053-02/S0002-9939-1975-0438320-2/). Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 53 (1975), no. 2, 497--500.

(See also Peter Shalen, [*Three-Manifolds and Baumslag-Solitar groups*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864199001674).
Topology Appl. 110 (2001), 113--118)

Comment: Are you sure that manifolds there can haave boundary?

Comment: Yes.  These groups are never the fundamental group of any 3-manifold.

Answer (score 12):

I recently heard of a result due to Aitchison and Reeves which shows that any finitely presented group arises as the fundamental group of a 3-dimensional *orbifold* (where fundamental group means the topological and not the orbifold fundamental group). In fact, they say that the orbifold can be taken to be the quotient of a closed oriented hyperbolic 3-manifold by an isometric involution with isolated fixed points, all modelled on $x\mapsto -x$.

(I'm certainly no expert on this topic, just passing on what I heard.)

Comment: I asked Aitchison, he only can make it to be fundamental group of $M^3/\mathbb Z_2$ 
where $M^3$ is closed orientable 3-manifold
and $\mathbb Z_2$ acts on $M$ with isolated fixed points.
The question  if $M$ can be made hyperbolic and $\mathbb Z_2$ action isometric is not yet resolved.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know - I must have misunderstood, although I thought I was quite insistent on knowing about the hyperbolic case. Still, that's quite a while ago now, probably I've misremembered things.

Answer (score 5):

If a finite group $G$ is (isomorphic to) the fundamental group of a three-manifold, then $G$ embeds in $\mathrm{SO}(4)$.

To see this, suppose that $M$ is a compact, connected three-manifold, possibly with boundary, having $G = \pi_1(M)$ finite. If $M$ has two-sphere boundary components, we can cap them off without changing the fundamental group.  Since free products of non-trivial groups are always infinite, we deduce that $G$ is freely indecomposible.  Appealing to the Poincaré conjecture [solved by Perelman], we have that $M$ is irreducible: all two-spheres in $M$ bound three-balls.

If $M$ is non-orientable, then a theorem of [Livesay](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970543) implies that $M$ is homeomorphic to the real projective plane crossed with a unit interval.

Thus we reduce to the case where $M$ is compact, oriented, connected, irreducible, and has finite fundamental group.  All boundary components of $M$ are now oriented, and of genus at least one.  Applying "one-half lives, one-half dies" we find that $M$ has no boundary components.  Appealing to the elliptic part of the geometrisation conjecture [solved by Perelman] we find that the universal cover of $M$ is the three-sphere, and the deck group, and thus $G$, is (conjugate to a) subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$. QED

A quick google search finds a paper of [Zimmermann](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2602v1) giving a readable introduction to the finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ - see section three of that paper.  One then has to determine which of these act freely.  Finally, there is another approach to this problem via spherical Seifert fibered spaces.

As a concrete example of a finite group that is not a three-manifold group, consider $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ where $p$ and $q$ are not coprime.  This is a isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$, but it cannot act freely.  [See Theorem 9.14 in [Hempel's book](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/chel-349) for a proof that, in this special case, avoids geometrisation.]