# Fundamental groups of non-orientable closed four-manifolds

Tags: manifolds, fundamental-group, 4-manifolds

The fundamental group of a closed orientable manifold is finitely presented, and every finitely presented group arises as the fundamental group of a closed orientable four-manifold; see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15411/21564).

Not every finitely presented group arises as the fundamental group of a closed non-orientable four-manifold. One necessary condition is that it contain an index two subgroup which corresponds to the orientation double cover. Is this the only restriction?

> Let $G$ be a finitely presented group with an index two subgroup. Is there a closed non-orientable four-manifold $M$ with $\pi_1(M) \cong G$?

Comment: Is this true in the case $G= \Bbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, it's the only restriction  i.e. the groups of non-orientable 4-manifolds are precisely the finitely presented groups that admit an epi-morphism to $\mathbb Z_2$.  The proof is pretty much the same, but you have to be careful with your 1-handle attachments to respect the epimorphism.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Thanks. Do you know of a reference where this is proved?

Comment: No, I'm saying take any of the proofs that 4-manifold fundamental groups can be any finitely-presented group and adapt it.  I'll just write it up as an answer below. . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group

$$ G = \langle g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_n | R_1, R_2, \cdots, R_m \rangle$$

One standard way to realize this as the fundamental group of a compact $4$-manifold is to construct a $5$-dimensional manifold.

1) Start with $D^5$ and attach a $1$-handle for every generator $g_i$.  Here the attaching map you use does not matter all that much but to get the process moving let's choose the attaching maps so the resulting handlebody will be orientable.  We will want to change this to answer your question. . . but this works for now.

2) You then attached a $2$-handle for every relator $R_j$.  The $2$-handles are attached via a circle mapping to the handlebody constructed in step (1).  A map from a circle to the previous handlebody is determined (up to homotopy) by a conjugacy-class in the fundamental group of the handlebody, i.e. a word in the free group, which is exactly what the relator $R_j$ is.  To make this a handle attachment you need to ensure the circle is in the boundary of the handlebody, and it is *embedded*, and has a trivial normal bundle.  This can all be achieved due to our choice of making the handlebody orientable in step (1) and a little transversality.

So this is a 5-manifold with the appropriate fundamental group.  But the manifold has boundary, so we check to see if the boundary (which is a closed manifold) also has the same fundamental group.  Here we use the fact that our 5-manifold deformation-retracts to a $2$-skeleton.  So by a little transversality, this $5$-manifold does have the same fundamental group as its boundary.  This is where we see we could have made this argument for $4$-manifolds, $5$-manifolds, etc, but this argument falls flat for $3$-manifold fundamental groups.

In the case you have an epi-morphism $G \to \mathbb Z_2$, you modify step (1) so that your $1$-handle attachment is orientation-reversing provided the loop maps to something non-trivial via the homomorphism $G \to \mathbb Z_2$.  Step (2) is unchanged.  The boundary $4$-manifold has the same fundamental group as the $5$-manifold constructed, again by dimension counting (transversality).

Comment: Hi Ryan. Sorry I didn't reply to this when you first answered, I can't remember why I didn't. In the final paragraph, you state that step (2) is unchanged if we allow some of the attachments of the $1$-handles to be orientation-reversing, but in the final sentence of step (2), you state that we use the fact that the handlebody from step (1) is orientable. Can we still attach the $2$-handles in the desired way even if the handlebody is non-orientable?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Yes, you can attach the 2-handles in the desired way.

Comment: OK, so in this way, one obtains a non-orientable closed four-manifold $M$ with $\pi_1(M) \cong G$ and if I'm not mistaken, the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1(M)$ can be identified with the epimorphism $G \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ under the identification $H^1(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(M), \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: correct.