# What is your favorite "strange" function?

Tags: big-list, gm.general-mathematics

There are many "strange" functions to choose from and the deeper you get involved with math the more you encounter. I consciously don't mention any for reasons of bias. I am just curious what you consider strange and especially like.

Please also give a reason why you find this function strange and why you like it. Perhaps you could also give some kind of reference where to find further information.

As usually: Please only mention one function per post - and let the votes decide :-)

Comment: http://m.reddit.com/r/math/comments/9txzv/what_is_your_favorite_strange_function/

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=8gHmxDSgcT0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: thank you... would like to see *this* community's answers and votes!

Comment: What restrictions, if any, are you placing on the functions? Do they have to be defined (or valued) on the reals or complex numbers, or are functions between arbitrary topological spaces, algebraic objects, unstructured sets etc. acceptable? What about functors between categories?

Comment: Counterexamples in analysis has some nice ones: http://books.google.nl/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=counterexamples+in+analysis&source=bl&ots=4Y9BGQEOfH&sig=Z4dCxQBCj1791QNR_gRbsR1F5-w&hl=nl&ei=ah1wTKmjCcfgOPaUkKsL&sa=X&oi=book_r

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A **[Brownian motion sample path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Some_properties_of_sample_paths)**.

These are about the most bizarrely behaved continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$ that you can think of.  They are nowhere differentiable, have unbounded variation, attain local maxima and minima in every interval... Many, many papers and books have been written about their strange properties.

Edit: As commented, I should clarify the term "sample path".  Brownian motion is a stochastic process $B_t$.  We say a sample path of Brownian motion has some property if the function $t \mapsto B_t$ has that property almost surely.  So, run a Brownian motion, and with probability 1 you will get a function with all these weird properties.

Comment: Pedantic, but maybe worth mentioning that these functions have these properties almost surely rather than certainly.

Answer (score 80):

The empty function $\emptyset:\emptyset\to\emptyset$ is quite strange when you first meet it.

Comment: For me, it makes a good argument that the "correct" value for $0^0$ is 1: it's the number of functions from a set with 0 elements to a set with 0 elements.

Comment: And, of course, it gives combinatorial meaning to the fact that 0! = 1, since the empty function is a bijection!

Comment: @Tom: Could you also please give a good reference. Wikipedia is not very exhaustive here... Thank you

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function. The function has all kinds of seemingly-contradictory properties: for instance it's continuous, bijective, order-preserving (and order-reversing!), but can't ever be evaluated.

Comment: @Tom:  …but it can always be very easily computed!  

Comment: Elsewhere I have raised the question of whether this function should be considered a constant function. On the one hand, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for every $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the domain; on the other hand, there is no $y$ in the codomain such that for every $x$ we have $f(x)=y$. I consider it non-constant.

Comment: On the other hand, there should be no doubt that the function $\emptyset\to S$ is constant if the set $S$ is nonempty.

Comment: A morphism in a category with terminal object $t$ may be called constant if it factors through $t$. According to this definition, $\emptyset \to S$ is constant iff $S$ is nonempty.

Comment: There are different sensible notions of a constant morphism: http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/constant+morphism

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Have you computed it for any value  in $\emptyset$?

Comment: What do you mean by "any"?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, here's the new nLab link:  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constant+morphism .

Answer (score 47):

**The Busy Beaver function**

Let Σ be a finite alphabet, for instance {0, 1}; let **M** be the set of Turing machines with alphabet Σ, and let **H** ⊆ **M** be the set of Turing machines that halt when given the empty string ε as input.

For each *M* ∈ **H**, Let *s*(*M*) be the number of steps performed by *M* before halting (when given ε as input).

Finally, let *S* : ℕ → ℕ be the function defined by

> *S*(*n*) = max {*s*(*M*) : *M* ∈ **H** and *M* has *n* states}

Notice that *S* is well-defined, since only finitely many Turing machines with *n* states exist.

In other words, *S*(*n*) is the maximum number of steps performed on ε among all halting Turing machines with *n* states. *S* is called the [Busy Beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver).

It turns out that *S* is uncomputable because it grows faster than any computable function, that is, for all recursive functions *f* : ℕ → ℕ we have *S*(*n*) > *f*(*n*) for large enough *n*, and in particular *f* is *o*(*S*).

Comment: In particular, it grows faster than the Ackermann function.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins It's faster than the Ackermann function iterated Graham's number of times.

Answer (score 34):

I like the Cantor function. A continuous, increasing function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ with derivative $0$ almost everywhere. See wiki article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: The same is true of $f(x)=\sum_{0<p/q<x} \frac{1}{2^q-1}$, where the sum is over all irreducible fractions $p/q$. But this function is also strictly increasing!

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant I realize it's been over four years, but 18 upvotes notwithstanding, for sure this function is discontinuous at every positive rational number? But I grant you that it is not only continuous, but differentiable at *irrational* points.

Comment: It is definitely discontinuous at rational points. At $p/q$ the difference between the limit from the left and from the right is $1/(2^q-1)$, which is definitely not 0. It is differentiable at irrational $x$, and moreover its derivative is 0 whenever it has one!

Answer (score 31):

The [Conway base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) has to be the weirdest function I know. This function is continuous nowhere, yet it satisfies the intermediate value theorem. Only John Conway...

Comment: The function is pretty funny too. It adds +, -, and . as digits in base-13, and then his function interprets it as a base-10 number.

Answer (score 30):

The [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) $A(n,m)$ is defined on the natural numbers by a very simple recursion, but the values grow enormously, almost beyond conception. This function completely transcends any simple-minded system of rates-of-growth based on polynomial, exponential, double-exponential and so on.

The first few values of the diagonal function $A(n) = A(n,n)$ are:

- $A(0) = 1$
- $A(1) = 3$
- $A(2) = 7$
- $A(3) = 61$
- $A(4) = 2^{2^{2^{65536}}}-3$
- $A(5)$ is vast, and can be described in terms of exponential stacks of $2$s, whose height is a stack of $2$s, etc. 5 times.
- $A(6)$ is so vast, it is best described using the Ackermann function itself.

The levels of the Ackerman function $A_n(m)=A(n,m)$ stratify the primitive recursive functions, in the sense that they are each primitive recursive, but every primitive recursive function is bounded by such a level of the Ackermann function. Thus, the Ackermann function itself is not primitive recursive, although it is computable in the sense of computability theory.

Comment: I never really thought of the Ackermann function as being *strange*, only *big*. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Ketil, yes, perhaps I agree. But what is strangely wonderful about it is that the recursive definition A(n+1,m+1)=A(n,A(n+1,m)) is so simple, and yet leads immediately to such incomprehensible growth.

Comment: @Joel I HATE the Ackermann function-I lost a whole letter grade on my set theory final because I couldn't construct the damn thing. 

Comment: I can't remember where (probably tvtropes), but when reading something about the Ackermann numbers (1 ^ 1, 2 ^^ 2, 3 ^^^ 3, etc), which are related to the Ackermann function, the joke was "it's always weird when looking at a sequence of numbers that goes: 1, 4, too big to count."

Answer (score 30):

I suppose the strangest function in mainstream mathematics is *Riemann zeta function* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

$
\zeta(s) =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} =
\frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots \;\;\;\;\;\;\;{Re}(s) >1.
$

It is part of one of the most important hypothesis  and is very influential in many branch of moder mathematics. It is actively used in many areas and is researched in many ways, it is not curiosity, or exotic example, but important mathematical being!

And is mysterious and strange! Take a look:
[image]

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality .

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: THAT IS SO COOL!

Answer (score 29):

I'm still quite impressed about $f(x)=\mathrm e^x$ …

Comment: Very true, me too! Could you please elaborate on why you consider this function "strange" - thank you.

Comment: Because of its stubborn nature: whether you differentiate it, or integrate it, it remains unmoved ;-)

Comment: There's a part of me which has never quite gotten over the Euler identity $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, which was perhaps the biggest intellectual thrill of my early teenage years... 

Answer (score 26):

[Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), also called the "popcorn function". It's continuous at all irrationals and discontinuous at all rationals. Here a picture:

[image: Thomae's function]

Comment: I wonder who Thomae was?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Johannes_Thomae

Answer (score 23):

The [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is particularly intriguing, as it's a function that's everywhere continuous, but nowhere differentiable.
$f(x)= \sum_{n=0} ^\infty a^n \cos(b^n \pi x)$
where 0<*a*<1, and *b* is a positive odd integer such that $ab > 1 + \frac{3\pi}{2}$.
It challenges the notion that, just because a function is continuous, it must also be differentiable in most places, which I think is pretty cool.

Comment: So is the Brownian sample path, also mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 21):

Please excuse me if I include two related functions in one answer. Any space filling curve is rather strange, at least for me. Let $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ be such a curve, that is, $\gamma$ is continuous and surjective. Let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$; then $x(t)$ (or $y(t)$) is my other candidate for strangest function: given any $z\in[0,1]$, $x^{-1}(z)$ has the cardinality of the continuum.

Answer (score 20):

**An unbounded operator with dense graph.**

In functional analysis, one deals with unbounded operators on Hilbert space, but usually ones that are closed, or are at least closable.  At the opposite end of the spectrum, one can construct linear operators whose graph is dense: for any pair $(x,y)$, there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $A x_n \to y$ !  It's not so easy even on $\mathbb{R}$ to come up with a function whose graph is dense, and the examples I think of aren't measurable.  But in infinite dimensions, you can find one that is linear!  It's just an illustration that facts that are trivial in finite dimensions can be horribly, horribly false in infinite dimensions.

A family of examples of this is constructed in

MR0782615 (86i:47052)
Lindsay, J. M.
A family of operators with everywhere dense graphs.
Exposition. Math. 2 (1984), no. 4, 375--378.

Interestingly, as an appplication, Lindsay uses such operators to prove that a **Brownian motion sample path** is nowhere differentiable --- which is my *other* favorite strange function!

Comment: Thank you - perhaps you could create a new post for Brownian Motion then, too?!?

Comment: The exotic solutions $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to Cauchy's functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ have dense graphs. They are obviously linear, but not continuous. (Not sure about measurability).

Comment: (I mean $\mathbb{Q}$-linear.)

Comment: There's one acting in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])\cup\mathcal{C}([2,3])$. I forgot what it acts like, though. :/ Can you help me? *(I'm pretty sure I saw it on wiki.)*

Answer (score 19):

The function defined by the power series $f(x)=x-x^2+x^4-x^8+x^{16}-\dots$ What is its limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from below? EDIT (This answer is a trick question.)

Comment: SPOILER (albeit 1.5+ years late): http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol8.html (and the PDF graph at http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/gamma_pic0.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

Minkowski's question mark function if only for the strange $?(\cdot)$ notation.

Comment: Could you give some more details - thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function - it is closely related with Cantor function mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: This article explains it well: [http://www.linas.org/math/mink-exact.pdf](http://www.linas.org/math/mink-exact.pdf)

Answer (score 13):

It is pretty obvious after you've seen it, but I like the crinkled curve from Halmos's Hilbert Space Problem book:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be an $L^2$ function, and define $t\mapsto g_t:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by $$g_t(x)=\chi_{(-\infty,t)}(x) \times f(x).$$

Then $g_t$ has the property that for all $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$ the secants $g_{t_2}-g_{t_1}$ and $g_{t_3}-g_{t_2}$ are mutually orthogonal.  (The curve turns a corner at every point.)

Comment: Heh, that's cute. 

Answer (score 11):

[The Fabius function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16829/what-are-your-favorite-instructional-counterexamples/17285#17285)

Answer (score 10):

Dirac delta function seems strange to me since the first time I saw it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: Well, technically the Dirac delta function is a distribution, and not a function.

Comment: good idea - could you perhaps put more flesh on it!?! Thank you!

Comment: with the "flesh" I esp. meant the answer (not so much the comment)

Comment: Well, it *is* a function, just not on the space you might think...

Comment: Haha, well *everything* is a function not on the space you might think.

Comment: I heard that after Schwartz got the Fields medal someone quipped "Now they're giving the Fields medal for integration by parts."

Comment: We used to say that Dirac's delta is the characteristic function of physicists: if you're a physicist, it's a function, otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: Well when Ngô Bâo Châu got the Fields medal, people said "Now they're giving Fields Medals for proving lemmas"...

Answer (score 10):

Interpreting your questions a bit liberally, I suggest the Goodstein sequence:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem

Answer (score 10):

f(x) = sin (1/x): (x not 0);
f(x) = 0 (x equals 0)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on that... thanks!

Comment: The functions one learns about early in studying mathematics are chosen to illustrate various "issues:' continuity, having a derivative, being periodic, etc. One of the functions one learns about in this way is y = sin(x). So while there are many functions that are "strange," the transition from y = sin (x) to y = sin (1/x) offers I feel lots of nice lessons about functions and their behavior. There are many web sites that use graphics to help one understand what is going on here. One such site is:

http://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/sin1overx/



Comment: As an added bonus, you get that the function is connected but not path connected...

Answer (score 9):

These functions like the Cantor function and the continuous-but-not-differentiable function are all well and good, but contrived - the only place you ever see them is as counterexamples. Here is a function that has many uses in Number Theory, and still manages to have a strange property or two. Let 
$x=h/k$ with $h$ and $k$ integers, $k>0$. Define $$s(x)=\sum_{c=1}^{k-1}((c/k))((ch/k))$$ where $((y))=0$ if $y$ is an integer, $((y))=\lbrace y\rbrace-1/2$ otherwise. It is easily proved that the sum depends only on the ratio of $h$ and $k$, not on their individual values, so $s$ is a well-defined function from the rationals to the rationals. It is known as the Dedekind sum; it came up originally in Dedekind's study of the transformation formula of the Dedekind $\eta$-function.

Now for the strange properties.

Hickerson, Continued fractions and density results for Dedekind sums, J Reine Angew Math 290 (1977) 113-116, MR 55 #12611, proved that the graph of $s$ is dense in the plane.

With Nick Phillips, I proved (Lines full of Dedekind sums, Bull London Math Soc 36 (2004) 547-552, MR 2005m:11075) that, with the exception of the line $y=x/12$, every line through the origin with rational slope passes through infinitely many points on the graph of $s$. We suspect that the points are dense on those lines, though we could only prove it for the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 8):

I like the [Theta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) which are given by Fourier-type series. They show up in many areas in mathematics. For example:

i)They are very important in the study of abelian varieties in algebraic geometry (for example, in the case of elliptic curves they are used in the proof of [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%25E2%2580%2593Jacobi_map) and are related to Weierstrass $\mathcal{P}-$function).

ii) They satisfy a number of interesting indentities. For example, in the one-dimensional case, they satisfy Jacobi's triple product identity which can be used to show [Jacobi's four square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%2527s_four-square_theorem)

iii) They can be used to solve algebraic equations degree equations explicitly (see [this link](http://library.wolfram.com/examples/quintic/main.html))

iv) In the one-dimensional case, they solve the heat equation.

Comment: But are they strange?

Comment: Well, they are definitely unusual in the sense that they are not taught in school. Also, the fact that they appear in such a variety of mathematical disciplines is also rather surprising. But I see your point.

Comment: I was going to write modular forms, but this is good enough.

Answer (score 8):

The Osgood curve ("[A Jordan Curve of Positive Area](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1986455)") is an injective map from [0,1] into $\mathbb{R}^2$ which traces out an image of positive area.  (This differs from standard space-filling curves, which are not injective.)

Answer (score 6):

A canonical example from elementary real analysis - the Blancmange function. Consider $f$ defined piecewise by

$f(x) = x - [x], \quad \text{if} \quad 0 \leq x- [x] \leq \frac{1}{2}$,

and

$f(x) = 1 - (x - [x]), \quad \text{if} \quad \frac{1}{2} < x - [x] < 1$,

(where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$). Then define the Blancmange function, $B$

$B(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n} f(2^{n}x)$.

The series converges by the Comparison Test, since $|f(2^{n}x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and it can be shown that $B$ is *uniformly continuous* but *nowhere differentiable*. Here a picture of the function:

[image: Blancmange function]

A tasty counterexample to the converse of "differentiability $\implies$ continuity".

Comment: Huh? The explicit you description you gave is just a sawtooth function.

Comment: My bad - I compiled my answer using LaTeX, however I didn't copy the complete post across properly. I will edit now.

Comment: Closely related is the tavuk göğsü function, replete with shredded chicken.

Comment: one can describe  $f(x)$ as the distance function from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 6):

The **Banach limit** assigns to every bounded sequence of real numbers a real number "limit" in a way that is linear, shift invariant, and agrees with the usual limit whenever it exists. Banach limits are among the mysterious examples of continuous linear functionals on $\ell^\infty$ that aren't represented by elements of $\ell^1$. Unfortunately, the Hahn-Banach theorem is used in the construction of the Banach limit, and the values aren't canonical. There's a precise definition at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit .

Answer (score 5):

Among the "special" functions encountered in analysis in my view Ingrid Daubechies' waveletes with compact support are the strangest.

Comment: Could you please give some more details? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

One can construct a natural 'metric' for the Riemann sphere which is equivalent to the spherical metric but which is singular on a dense set of points of the Riemann sphere though remains $L^1$ integrable.

These are built from degree 2 rational maps (first constructed by Mary Rees) which have the whole Riemann sphere as their Julia sets, and have the orbits of their critical points also dense.  The Carlesson-Jones-Yoccoz construction of a expanding metric for critically-finite rational maps actually extends to this case, and we get a metric in which this Julia set actually *looks* as if it was hyperbolic!

[The details are worked out in my PhD thesis, never published as I decided that computer algebra suited me better than complex dynamics].

Answer (score 5):

Since Mariano took my favorite already, I'll go with the stopping time function for the 3x+1 problem: http://www.ieeta.pt/~tos/3x+1.html

Answer (score 5):

Fix a probability $p < 1/2$ of winning an unfair coin toss. For $x \in [0,1]$ rational, let $f(x)$ be the probability that, if you started with $x$ dollars, you could make it to 1 dollar through optimal betting* on the outcome of these coin flips. This function $f(x)$ is obviously weakly increasing on $[0,1]$ (in fact strictly). Less obvious is that it extends to a continuous function on $[0,1]$, whose derivative exists almost everywhere, but that derivative is $0$.

http://www.maa.org/joma/Volume8/Siegrist/RedBlack.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe no one has mentioned the [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html):
[image]
(I guess it's up to me to bring it up...)

Comment: If you plant a post of unit height at every point in $\{(x, y) : x, y \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$ and stand at the origin, looking in the direction of $(1,1)$, you will see this picture.

Comment: @Max It's been 3 years since your comment, but I don't think that's precisely the case.  Standing at the origin you will see a pole at x-coordinate $\arctan \frac{m}{n}$ with height $\frac{1}{n}$.  Here, the pole of height $\frac{1}{n}$ is at x-coordinate $\frac{m}{n}$ instead.

Comment: This image shows  a modified version of Dirichlet function  = Thomae function  or small Riemann function , see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html

Answer (score 5):

Nonconstant continuous locally recurrent functions are quite unintuitive. A real-valued function is *locally recurrent* on $\mathbb R$ if for every $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and every deleted neighborhood $N(x_0)$ of $x_0$, there exists $x\in N(x_0)$ for which $f(x)=f(x_0)$. Thus in some sense a nonconstant continuous locally recurrent function looks everywhere like $x\sin(1/x)$ at $x=0$. See papers in the *American Math. Monthly* of Bush (1962), Marcus (1963), and Mauldon (1965).

Answer (score 3):

Any of the isomorphisms $\mathbb{C}'\to S^{1}$, where $S^{1}$ is the unit circle and $\mathbb{C}'$ is the non-zero complex numbers, with the group operation for both being multiplication.

Comment: Could you please give an example of such an isomorphism, or at least an argument to prove that these groups are isomorphic? I find it quite surprising.

Comment: The proof of their existence comes from the structure theorem for divisible abelian groups. Both are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Q}\times \bigoplus_\omega \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @DanielMiller perhaps I'm being dense, but surely $S^1$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Q}\times\bigoplus_\omega\mathbb{Q}$? the former is uncountable, but the latter is a cartesian product of two countable sets and is hence countable. ($\bigoplus_\omega\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ with finite support)

Comment: You're right. The subscript should be $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @DanielMiller now I'm being a bit pedantic, for which I apologize, but I think it should be $2^{\aleph_0}$, unless we're assuming the continuum hypothesis. anyway +1, I agree this isomorphism is a very bizarre function indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Characteristic p commutative algebra leads naturally to the construction of various
continuous functions on [0,1]^m that have beautiful self-similarity properties;
for explication and some pictures see:

```
Pedro Teixeira, Syzygy gap fractals--I, arXiv 1008.0583
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a function f: f(f(x)) = exp(x).

Comment: Could you give a reference to understand more about it - thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about the function given by the Banach-Tarski paradox? This maps a ball into two copies of the same size ball, and is composed of isometries on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple construction to illustrate [Nate Eldredge's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22189/what-is-your-favorite-strange-function/22191#22191) about functions with dense graphs. Pick any $\mathbb{R}$-vector space *E* with a norm. On *E*, choose a *non-continuous* linear form $L: E \to \mathbb{R}$; now this can only be done if $\dim(E)=\infty$, of course.

Then, pick *y* such that $L(y)=1$, and let $T: E \to E$ be defined by $Tx=x-L(x)y$. Then obviously *T* maps *E* onto the kernel of *L*; it is not difficult to prove that $\ker (L)$ must be dense in *E* for any non-continuous *L* (the two conditions are even equivalent), and thus the graph of *T* must be dense in $E \times E$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the nth term in the Fibonacci sequence

$F_{n} = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left(\cfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left(\cfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$

This is interesting because it is a non-recursive expression for the Fibonacci sequence and also because it involves the golden ratio.

Comment: Yes, but isn't $\,x^n\,$ defined recursively? You still don't avoid recursion. Also, the golden ratio is not rational. If you define $\,\phi\,$ as the positive root of $\,x^2=x+1\,$ then $\,\phi^n = F_{n-1}+F_n\phi\,$ so $\,\phi^n\,$ is defined by $\,F_n.$

Answer (score -1):

I like the beauty and *mysticism* of Euler's identity:

$$f(\theta) = e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$$