# Strange real functions

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I know there are a lot of strange functions $f~:~\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

I'm looking for an "elementary but complete" exposition of a result discovered by W. Sierpi\'nski and A. Zygmund in "Sur une fonction qui est discontinue sur tout ensemble de puissance du continu." *Fund. Math.*, vol. 4, pp.316–318, 1923 stating (in simple form) that there exist a function $f~:~\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  such that for every non empty open interval $I$, $f(I)=\mathbb R$ .

And also, a probably well-known fact for experts in real analysis:
If an arbitrary continuous function $f~:~ [0,1] \to \mathbb R$  is given, is it true that $f_{|D}$ is monotonic on some dense set $D\subset [0,1]$ or some set $D$ of positive measure?

It seems to be true if I replace "dense set" by "perfect subset" (according to Jack Brown).
If this is not true an example is highly appreciated.

Comment: The restriction of the absolute value function to $[-1,1]$ does not seem to be monotonous on any dense subset of $[-1,1]$.


Comment: The first question is a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32126/function-with-range-equal-to-whole-reals-on-every-open-set.

Comment: @Mariano, indeed it is obvious so I slightly changed the question.


Comment: Not sure what the change was but Mariano's answer remains valid: $|x-c|$ is a counterexample where $c$ is any inner point of the domain. 

Comment: @fedja: Portland added the option that the set is not dense, but has positive measure. 

Comment: Ah, OK. Take the Weierstrass function $\sum_k (n_k)^{-1/2}\sin n_k x$ with very fast growing $n_k$ then. Each point outside an exceptional set of measure $0$ lies in a "valley" of each term with sufficiently large index (the previous terms have too small derivatives and the following terms are too small to change that). So, for almost every point $x$, the portion of $y$ with $f(y)>f(x)$ is noticeable on both sides of $x$ in a sequence of intervals centered at $x$. But a.e. point of a set of positive measure is a density point. 

Comment: Fedja, could you expand your comment into an answer? 

Comment: Sure, Joel, if you tell which part of it gives you trouble (just to write essentially the same text in another window won't make much sense)

Answer (score 5):

Although you asked about continuous functions, here is an example of a discontinuous 
function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$
which is not monotone on any measurable set with positive measure.

Let $V\subset [0,1]$ be the usual Vitali set, selecting one
element from each equivalence class under translation by
the rationals. Thus, $V$ is not measurable, and the
translates $V+q$ (working modulo 1) for rational $q$ are
disjoint and cover $[0,1]$. It follows that none of the
translates $V+q$ contains a measurable set of positive measure. Enumerate
the rationals $\mathbb{Q}=\{ q_n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$,
and let $f(x)=n$ for $x\in V+q_n$. Thus, $f$ is constant on
each $V+q$, and the range of $f$ involves only natural
number values. Suppose that $f$ is monotone on a measurable
set $A\subset [0,1]$. If $f|A$ is constant or has only
finitely many values, then $A$ will be contained in the
union of finitely many $V+q$, and hence not have positive
measure. Otherwise, $A$ must contain points from infinitely
many $V+q$, and since the range is contained in
$\mathbb{N}$, it must be that $f$ is nondecreasing on $A$.
For any $a\in A$, note that if $f(a)=n$, then $A\cap [0,a]$
is contained in the union of $V+q_m$ for $m\leq n$, a
finite number of translations of $V$. Thus $A\cap [0,a]$
has measure $0$ for any $a\in A$, and it follows that $A$
has measure $0$ altogether.

Comment: I seem to recall that a discontinuous additive function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ can't be bounded (let alone monotone) on any measurable set with positive measure. But maybe I remember wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Every continuous function is monotone on a perfect set:

Let $I=[0,1]$ and let $f:I\to\mathbb R$ be continuous (actually, Borel-measurable is enough for what follows).
Let $[I]^2$ be the set of 2-element subsets of $I$.
For all $\{a,b\}\in[I]^2$ with $a\lt b$ let $c(a,b)=0$ if $f(a)\lt f(b)$ and $c(a,b)=1$, otherwise.
Since $f$ is continuous, the set 
$$\{(a,b)\in I^2:a\lt b\wedge c(a,b)=0\}$$
is Borel in $I^2$.
By a theorem of Galvin, there is a perfect set $P\subseteq I$ such that $c$ is constant on
$[P]^2$.
From the definition of $c$ is follows that $f$ is monotone on $P$.

A source for Galvin's theorem is Kechris' book on Classical Descriptive Set Theory.
If you want to avoid the use of Galvin's theorem, you can use the full strength of 
continuity:

Since every nonempty open subset of $I$ contains a perfect set, we may assume $f$ is not monotone on any nonempty open subset of $I$.
Now every nonempty open subset of $I$ has a two-element subset on which $f$ is strictly
increasing.

A straight-forward perfect set construction now gives you a perfect set on which $f$ is
strictly increasing.

Comment: Hi Stefan. I  edited what you wrote a bit so the brackets and $\lt$ signs show.

Comment: Thanks, Andres.  I was just in the process of editing my answer when you edited it.  For some reason, my strict-inequality characters don't show properly.

Comment: Yeah, they don't. I use \lt instead.

Comment: @stefan, thanks, here is another proof http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-108-02/S0002-9939-1990-0987607-1/S0002-9939-1990-0987607-1.pdf 
BTW my question is about dense subset or subset with positive measure 

Comment: @Portland:  Thanks for the reference.  Apparently I have reproved Theorem 1.2 of the paper you mention.  The article also says that you cannot necessarily get a set of positive measure on which the function is differentiable and monotone.  

Concerning density: I read your question, but it sounded like you 
where not absolutely sure even about the existence of a perfect set.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate all rational intervals, let them be $\Delta_1$, $\Delta_2$ and so on. Let $K_i\subset \Delta_i$ be a perfect nowhere dense set (of cardinality continuum, of course) so that $K_i$ are mutually disjoint. It is easy to construct such sets one by one. Then map each $K_i$ to $\mathbb{R}$ bijectively and define $f$ in other points (not belonging to $\cup K_i$) arbitrarily.