# If $f$ is infinitely differentiable then $f$ coincides with a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f$ be an *infinitely differentiable function* on $[0,1]$ and suppose that for each $x \in [0,1]$ there is an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$. Then does $f$ coincide on $[0,1]$ with some polynomial? If yes then how.

I thought of using Weierstrass approximation theorem, but couldn't succeed.

Comment: This seems like a homework problem in a 1st year course on calculus. 

Comment: This is a jewel, I will try to recall the solution.

Comment: Chandru, my suspicion is that instead of "for each $x \in [0,1]$, there is an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it said there is an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: ......OK, maybe this is subtler than I thought........

Comment: @Ryn: no, this is a classic little problem.  @Michael: the problem is correct as stated. 

Comment: This is basically a double-starred exercise in the book "Linear Analysis" by Bela Bollobas (second edition), and presumably uses the Baire Category Theorem. Since it is double-starred, it is probably very hard!! Solutions are not given, and even single starred questions in that book can be close to research level.

However, the version in that book has $f$ on the whole real line, and $f^{(m)}(x) = 0$ for ALL $m>n$.

So are you sure your question is correct, since it's assuming a lot less but coming to roughly the same conclusion?

Comment: In view of Ryan's and Zen's comments, can the author, please, indicate the origin of the question? 

Comment: Like Zen, I have seen a version of this question before set as an "exercise" - the tricky part, which I never solved on my own, is what to do once you've done the "obvious" Baire category part. Here I say "obvious" in the context of it being one of several BaireCat flavoured exercises in a batch, not "so obvious that everyone should have thought of it"

Comment: I agree with Andrew L.'s opinion(but not the more extreme part of it). If such hard questions are given as homework for a first year calculus course, then there will be complaints about the instructor, and indeed about the department. It is my modest contention that anyone who criticizes a question as homework should be able to substantiate it by giving a short solution in the comments. This doesn't take much effort. What I am preaching is just a variant of "All right, but let the one who has never sinned throw the first stone!". Before closing a question as homework, first solve it.

Comment: @Qiaochu, You're quite right; I was hasty.

Comment: Also asked here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64246/

Comment: in cooking up my own solution to this classic problem which I've already encountered elsewhere, I came to wonder wether there are any closed, denumerable sets of reals that have no isolated points... Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: nevermind, I think I have one.

Comment: Olivier: you are referring to the notion of "perfect set", and there are no nonempty countable perfect sets. The argument is essentially a Baire category argument. See http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/topo/proofs/pfctuncb.html 

Comment: This is stated as an exercise in Rudin's "Principles", and yes, it gets assigned as freshman's homework (at least where I come from). Originally it was formulated and solved in 1930's by Banach, if I remember correctly. I will try to dig up a more precise reference.

Comment: @Margaret: Thanks, I would like to know the history of this problem as well. I will be thankful if you could provide me with the history. 


Comment: Margaret, I looked through Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (3rd edition) but didn't find this exercise. What page is it on? Also, where do you come from (that this exercise is assigned to freshmen)? 


Comment: My memory failed me on this problem. The only thing I am now sure about is that it was assigned as a freshman homework when I was a student at Jagiellonian U. in Krakow, Poland, a little more than 20 years ago (no, I did not solve it then). Rudin was used as a supplementary text, but I must have seen it printed somewhere else (or was it added in the Polish translation?). Proving various properties of function spaces via Baire category was a Polish specialty in 1930's, but, as indicated by @juan, this particular theorem apparently has different origin. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TheMathemagician It's not too far away from a homework for first year calculus or analysis, which doesn't mean that it's easy, but only that it could be written in elementary language within a considerable length. In my university, the fact is the derivative of a differentiable function is continuous at a point, is left as a homework exercise, which is also, in fact, a consequence of Baire's category theorem.

Comment: @FrankScience, I suppose that one can derive any true statement from anything, but is there a sense other than this formal one in which the continuity of a differentiable function is a consequence of Baire's category theorem?

Comment: [@S.Carnahan](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial#comment161636_34059), the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64246/strange-non-analytic-smooth-functions) you reference gives the stronger hypothesis suggested by [@‍ZenHarper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial#comment77911_34059).

Comment: @LSpice I don't know whether I misunderstood your response. What I said is that, given a differentiable function (on $\mathbb R$, say) $f$, then the derivative $f'$ (not $f$) should be continuous at some point $x_0\in\mathbb R$. I don't think that it's tautological.

Comment: @FrankScience, no, I misunderstood you, not the other way around.  I misread it as the totally elementary statement "a differentiable function is continuous."  Sorry!

Comment: @TheMathemagician Get ready! This was a problem in a problem book written by Michal Krych for the Gottwald High School in Warsaw. I did solve the problem in the 10th grade and many other students did solve it. You are asking for a regularly offered course at a university so high school should count. Three more answers and I will look for your YouTube chanel! If you do not appear naked I will vote down all your questions and answers :)

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz You'll be waiting a long time, Piotr. The Gottwald HS in Warsaw is one of the premier schools in Europe. Maybe I should have said 10. My point was this is NOT a standard question for the average first year university student. You clearly were a superior student and consequently attended superior courses.(By the way, I'm a HUGE fan of your online handwritten lecture notes. You're clearly a terrific teacher. Your students are lucky to have you in Pittsburgh.)

Comment: @TheMathemagician I hope you did not get offended by my joke :) Thank you for your nice comments. I indeed put a lot of effort to write useful notes and make the available to everyone. Also I am a new user of Mathoverflow and I do my best to write clear and detailed answers like the one below. I want it to be a website with answers ready to use.

Comment: This has been an interesting discussion. The conclusion seems to be that Polish mathematicians consider this problem much less difficult than the rest of the world. Of course this isn't surprising since functional analysis has a long   and rich tradition in Poland.

Comment: What a coincidence! I've just presented this result to my honors students. The earliest I could track the result is a 1954 Comptes Rendues note by some spaniards; see Example  17.2.24 of  these lecture notes https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Hon_Calc_Lectures.pdf

Comment: This result is due to two Catalonian Mathematicians, Balaguer and Corominas - F. Sunyer i Balaguer, &  E. Corominas,
*Sur des conditions pour qu’une fonction infiniment
dérivable soit un polynôme*, 
Comptes Rendues Acad. Sci. Paris, 
**238** (1954), 558-559.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The proof is by contradiction. Assume $f$ is not a polynomial.

Consider the following closed sets:
$$
S_n = \{x: f^{(n)}(x) = 0\} 
$$
and
$$
X = \{x: \forall (a,b)\ni x: f\restriction_{(a,b)}\text{ is not a polynomial} \}. 
$$

It is clear that $X$ is a non-empty closed set without isolated points. Applying Baire category theorem to the covering $\{X\cap S_n\}$ of $X$ we get that there exists an interval $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\cap X$ is non-empty and
$$
(a,b)\cap X\subset S_n
$$
for some $n$. Since every $x\in (a,b)\cap X$ is an accumulation point we also have that $x\in S_m$ for all $m\ge n$ and $x\in (a,b)\cap X$.

Now consider any maximal interval $(c,e)\subset ((a,b)-X)$. Recall that $f$ is a polynomial of some degree $d$ on $(c,e)$. Therefore $f^{(d)}=\mathrm{const}\neq 0$ on $[c,e]$. Hence $d< n$. (Since either $c$ or $e$ is in $X$.)

So we get that $f^{(n)}=0$ on $(a,b)$ which is in contradiction with $(a,b)\cap X$ being non-empty.

Comment: Thank you! Filling in all the details to this outline is a fantastic exercise in basic real analysis and topology. It strikes me as a great "capstone" to a relevant course. It went through at least 20 relevant topics/ideas: (in roughly decreasing order of complexity) Baire Category Theorem, Heine-Borel, infs/sups (so LUB property of R), compactness, Cauchy/convergent sequences/completeness, (infinite) differentiability, continuity, connectedness, perfect sets, limit points (from the sides), induction, isolated points, open/closed sets, interiors, derivatives of polynomials, and boundedness.

Comment: Is a similar statement true for functions of n>1 variables?

Comment: @AlexW In that case, the natural hypothesis would be that for each $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a multi-index $\alpha=\alpha(x_0)$ such that $\left. \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} f}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \partial x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}\right\vert_{x_0}=0$. Essentially the same argument works, by appropriately replacing intervals $(a,b)$ as in this answer with open balls. In particular there are only countably many multi-indices so Baire's theorem applies.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Let $f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_2}$, $\alpha=(1,0)$. Then $f^{(\alpha)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ but $f$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @AlexW You're right, thank you!

Comment: Should $x: \forall (a,b)\ni x$ instead be $x: \exists(a,b)\ni x$ ? If $f\restriction_{(a, b)}$ is required to hold for *every* interval $(a, b)$, then $X$ would need to be either empty or the entire interval $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 38):

Note that [The Fabius function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16829/what-are-your-favorite-instructional-counterexamples/17285#17285) is nowhere analytic but admits a *dense* set of points where all but finitely many derivatives vanish.

Answer (score 32):

The theorem:

Theorem: Let $f(x)$ be $C^\infty$ on $(c,d)$ such that for every point $x$ in the 
interval there exists an integer $N_x$ for which $f^{(N_x)}(x)=0$; then $f(x)$ 
is a polynomial.

is due to two Catalan mathematicians:

F. Sunyer i Balaguer,  E. Corominas, Sur des conditions pour qu'une fonction infiniment dérivable soit un polynôme. Comptes Rendues Acad. Sci. Paris, 238 (1954), 558-559.

F. Sunyer i Balaguer,  E. Corominas, Condiciones para que una función infinitamente derivable sea un polinomio. Rev. Mat. Hispano Americana, (4), 14 (1954).

The proof can also be found in the book (p. 53):

W. F. Donoghue, Distributions and Fourier Transforms, Academic Press, New York, 1969.

I will never forget it because  in an "Exercise" of the "Opposition" to 
became "Full Professor" I was posed the following problem:

What are the real  functions  indefinitely differentiable on an interval such that 
a derivative vanish at each point?

Answer (score 31):

Let me add one more solution. **It is not really different from the accepted one, but it includes all details.** The problem is that a student without sufficient experience will not even see necessity to fill details.

> **Theorem.**
>   *If $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a nonnegative integer $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$, then $f$ is a
>   polynomial.*

The following exercise shows that the result cannot be to easy.

> **Exercise.** *Prove that there is a function $f\in C^{1000}(\mathbb{R})$ which is not a polynomial, but has the property described in the above
>   theorem.*

***Proof of the theorem.***
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ be the union of all open intervals $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$
such that $f|_{(a,b)}$ is a polynomial. The set $\Omega$ is open, so
$$
\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^N (a_i, b_i)\, ,
\qquad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   (1)
$$
where $a_i<b_i$ and $(a_i, b_i)\cap (a_j, b_j) = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$, $1\leq N\leq\infty$.
Observe that $f|_{(a_i, b_i)}$ is a polynomial
(Why?)*.
We want to prove that $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$. First we will prove that
$\overline{\Omega}=\mathbb{R}$. To this end it suffices to prove that for any
interval $[a,b]$, $a<b$ we have $[a,b]\cap\Omega\neq\emptyset$.
Let
$$
E_n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\, f^{(n)}(x)=0\}\, .
$$
The sets $E_n\cap [a,b]$ are closed and
$$
[a,b]=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty E_n\cap [a,b]\, .
$$
Since $[a,b]$ is complete, it follows from the Baire theorem that for some $n$
the set $E_n\cap [a,b]$ has nonempty interior (in the topology of $[a,b]$),
so there is $(c,d)\subset E_n\cap [a,b]$ such that $f^{(n)}=0$ on $(c,d)$.
Accordingly $f$ is a polynomial on $(c,d)$ and hence
$$
(c,d)\subset\Omega\cap [a,b]\neq\emptyset.
$$
The set $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\Omega$ is closed and hence complete.
It remains to prove that $X=\emptyset$. Suppose not.
Observe that every point $x\in X$ is an accumulation point of the set,
i.e. there is a sequence $x_i\in X$, $x_i\neq x$, $x_i\to x$. Indeed,
otherwise $x$ would be an isolated point, i.e. there would be two intervals
$$
(a,x),\, (x,b)\subset\Omega,\ x\not\in\Omega\, . 
\qquad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$
The function $f$ restricted to each of the two intervals is a polynomial, say
of degrees $n_1$ and $n_2$. If $n>\max\{ n_1, n_2\}$, then
$f^{(n)}=0$ on $(a,x)\cup (x,b)$. Since
$f^{(n)}$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, it must be zero on the entire interval
and hence $f$ is a polynomal of degree $\leq n-1$ on $(a,b)$, so
$(a,b)\subset\Omega$ which contradicts (2).

The space $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\Omega$ is complete.
Since
$$
X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X\cap E_n\, ,
$$
the second application of the Baire theorem
gives that $X\cap E_n$ has a nonempty interior in the topology of $X$, i.e.
there is an interval $(a,b)$ such that
$$
X\cap (a,b)\subset X\cap E_n\neq\emptyset\, .
\qquad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)
$$
Accordingly $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in X\cap (a,b)$.
Since for every $x\in X\cap (a,b)$ there is a sequence $x_i\to x$, $x_i\neq x$
such that $f^{(n)}(x_i)=0$
it follows from the definition of the derivative that
$f^{(n+1)}(x)=0$ for every $x\in X\cap (a,b)$, and by induction
$f^{(m)}(x)=0$ for all $m\geq n$ and all $x\in X\cap (a,b)$.

We will prove that $f^{(n)}=0$ on $(a,b)$. This will imply that
$(a,b)\subset\Omega$ which is a contradiction with (3).
Since $f^{(n)}=0$ on $X\cap (a,b)=(a,b)\setminus\Omega$ it remains to prove that
$f^{(n)}=0$ on $(a,b)\cap\Omega$.
To this end it suffices to prove that for any interval
$(a_i, b_i)$ that appears in (1) such that
$(a_i, b_i)\cap (a,b)\neq\emptyset$, $f^{(n)}=0$ on $(a_i, b_i)$. Since
$(a,b)$ is not contained in $(a_i, b_i)$ one of the endpoints belongs
to $(a,b)$, say $a_i\in (a,b)$. Clearly
$a_i\in X\cap (a,b)$ and hence $f^{(m)}(a_i)=0$ for all $m\geq n$.
If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ on $(a_i, b_i)$, then
$f^{(k)}$ is a nonzero constant on $(a_i, b_i)$, so $f^{(k)}(a_i)\neq 0$ by
continuity of the derivative. Thus $k<n$ and hence
$f^{(n)}=0$ on $(a_i,b_i)$.
$\Box$

> **Exercise.**
>   *As the previous exercise shows the theorem is not true if we only assume that $f\in C^{1000}$. Where did we use in the proof the
>   assumption $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?*

---

*It suffices to prove that $f$ is a polynomial on every compact
subinterval $[c,d]\subset (a_i, b_i)$. This subinterval has a finite covering by
open intervals
on which $f$ is a polynomial. Taking an integer $n$ larger than the maximum
of the degrees of these polynomials, we see that $f^{(n)}=0$ on $[c,d]$
and hence $f$ is a polynomial of degree $<n$ on $[c,d]$.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but I am confused about the sentence "The set $\Omega$ is open so $\Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i, b_i)$ where $a_i < b_i$ and $(a_i, b_i) \cap (a_j, b_j) = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$}. Is the last part (empty intersections of intervals) correct? It seems a bit at odds with the claim further down that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Vincent I edited my proof, see  formula (1). Is it okay now?

Comment: Huh no, now it is even more confusing. I understand that open sets are a union of intervals, but not that they are a union of *disjoint* intervals. Take the case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, I don't see any way of writing this as a union of non-overlapping intervals (let alone a finite number of such intervals as the new formula (1) suggests). But on closer inspection I think the condition $(a_i, b_i) \cap (a_j, b_j)  = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$ which is causing my concern is not being used further down the proof, is it?

Comment: @Vincent $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$. I never said that the intervals are finite.

Comment: If we assume $f\in C^{1000}$, then the sets $E_n$ for $n>1000$ are not guaranteed to be closed. For the example, consider $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$,  $f(x) = x^{1001}$ if $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 16):

For what it's worth, I post my solution. I assume $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which makes no difference but lets me use one less symbol.

1. Let $A_n = \{ x \in R \mid f^{(n)}(x) = 0 \}$, $E_n$ the interior of $A_n$. Clearly $E_n \subset E_m$ for $n < m$, and by Baire $E_n$ is eventually not empty.
2. Each $E_n$ is a countable union of open segments. It is easy to see that in passing from $E_n$ to $E_{n+1}$ new segments can appear, but those already in $E_n$ remain unchanged. Moreover two such segments are never adiacent.
3. By this remark is it enough to prove that $\bigcup E_n = \mathbb{R}$. Indeed if this holds and $E_n \neq \emptyset$, then $E_n = \mathbb{R}$, which implies the thesis. Otherwise the points in the boundary of $E_n$ don't appear in the union.
4. Let $E = \bigcup E_n$, $B$ its complementary set, and assume by contradiction $B \neq \emptyset$. $B$ is itself a complete metric space, hence can apply Baire to it. So for some $k$ we find that $A_k \cap B$ has non-empty interior in $B$. This means that there is an interval $I$ such that $B \cap I \subset A_k$ (and $B \cap I \neq \emptyset$).
5. From remark 2, $B$ has no isolated points. The contradiction that we want to find is that $I \setminus B \subset A_k$. Indeed from this it follows that $I \subset A_k$, hence $E_k \cap B \neq \emptyset$.
6. By construction $I \setminus B$ is a union of intervals which appear in some $E_n$. Take such an interval $J$, say $J \subset E_N$ (where $N$ is minimal), and let $x$ be one end point of $J$ (which is not on the boundary of $I$). Then $x \in I \cap B \subset A_k$, so $f^{(k)}(x) = 0$. Moreover $x$ is not isolated in $B$, so it is the limit of a sequence $x_i$ of points in $B$.
7. By the same argument $f^{(k)}(x_i) = 0$. Between two point where the $k$-th derivative vanish lies a point where the $k+1$-th does, so by continuity we find $f^{(k+1)}(x) = 0$. Similarly we find $f^{(m)}(x) = 0$ for all $m \geq k$. On $J$ $f$ is a polynomial of degree $N$; it follows that $N \leq k$, and we conclude that $J \subset E_k$. Since $J$ was arbitrary we conclude that $I \setminus B \subset E_k$, which we have shown to be a contradiction.

Comment: Hi--

Thanks a lot. Now, does this remain true if we replace $[0,1]$ by $\mathbb{R}$ or $[a,b]$

Comment: Yes, of course. The proof is the same.

Comment: In step $3$, what about functions of the form $e^{-1/x}$. They can have a derivative $0$ on an interval and all future ones zero on the boundary.

Comment: Those functions have all derivatives 0 in a point, not on a whole interval

Comment: @AndreaFerretti, just for me to understanding well: are you proving that if for all $x$ there is a natural $n_x$ such that $n\geq n_x$ implies $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ then $f$ is polynomial? I just want to realize what implies $E_m\subset E_n$ in your proof.

Comment: E_n is the interior of A_n. For a point in E_n you have a whole interval where the nth derivative vanishes identically, hence all subsequent derivatives vanish

Comment: @AndreaFerretti of course, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe unuseful, but it remains true if you consider $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$.

Try showing that

**Lemma.** Let $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ be a nonempty interval and $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$. If $f$ is not a polynomial on $I$, then there exists a compact subset $J\Subset I$ in which $f$ is not a polynomial. Moreover, $f(x)\neq 0\;\forall x\in J$.

Answer (score 7):

In Andrey Gogolev's answer the following two assertions appear:

"It is clear that $X$ is a non-empty . . . set" and "Now consider any maximal interval
$(c,e) \subset ((a,b) - X)$.  Recall that $f$ is a polynomial of some degree $d$ on
$(c,e)$."

These are true, but perhaps not transparently obvious.  In attempting to fill the gaps, I
developed a variation of the proof which requires neither the observation that $X$ has no
isolated points nor any argument about degrees of polynomials.  Here is my adaptation,
borrowed freely from Gogolev:

I use the symbol "$\bot$" for "contradiction."

Define $I = [0,1]$ and $X = \{x \in I: \forall (a,b) \ni x: f|_{(a,b) \cap I} \; is \;
not \; a \; polynomial\}$ .

We first establish the following:

Lemma: Suppose $[c,d] \subset I$ is an interval on which $f$ coincides with a polynomial
$p$.  Then there exists a maximal subinterval $[cm,dm]$ having the properties $[c,d]
\subset [cm,dm] \subset I$ and $f = p$ on $[cm,dm]$.  Furthermore, $cm \in X \cup \{0\}$
and $dm \in X \cup \{1\}$.

Proof: Let $cm$ = LUB $\{x: f(x) \neq p(x)\} \cup \{0\}$ and $dm$ = GLB $\{x: f(x)
\neq p(x)\} \cup \{1\}$.  It is clear that $[cm,dm]$ is maximal.  Supppose that $cm
\not \in X$ and $cm \neq 0$.  Then we can find another interval $(u,v)$ with $cm \in (u,v)
\subset I$ on which $f$ coincides with a polynomial $q$.  But on $[cm,v]$ we have $f = p =
q$, whence $f = p$ on $[u,dm]$.  Since $u < cm$, we see that $[cm,dm]$ is not maximal
($\bot$).  Therefore, $cm \in X$ or $cm = 0$. Likewise, $dm \in X$ or $dm = 1$.

Now we begin the proof-by-$\bot$ of the main result.  Suppose that $f$ is not a polynomial
on $I$.

If $X = \emptyset$, we begin with any $[c,d]$, and the lemma tells us that $cm = 0$ and
$dm = 1$, so $f$ is a polynomial on $I$ ($\bot$).  Thus, $X \neq \emptyset$.  Now define
$S_n = \{x: f^{(n)}(x) = 0\}$.  $X$ and $S_n$ are clearly closed.  Applying the Baire
category theorem to the covering $\{X \cap S_n\}$ of the complete metric space $X$, we get
that there exists an interval $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b) \cap X \neq \emptyset$ and $(a,b)
\cap X \subset S_n$ for some $n$.  (It is important here that $S_n$ is closed.)

Put $J = (a,b) \cap I$, and let $a1$ and $b1$ be the left and right end-points of $J$. 
(Observe that it is possible that $a1 = 0$ or $b1 = 1$, so J may not be open.)  If $J
\subset S_n$, then $f$ is a polynomial on $J$, whence $(a,b) \cap X = (a,b) \cap I \cap X
= J \cap X = \emptyset$ ($\bot$).  Thus, we can choose a point $t \in J - S_n$.  Now $t
\not \in X$, since $(a,b) \cap X \subset S_n$.  Therefore, we can find an interval $(c,d)
\ni t$ such that $f$ coincides with a polynomial $p$ on $(c,d) \cap I$.  Furthermore, $f =
p$ on the closure of $(c,d) \cap I$, which is an interval of the form $[c1,d1] \subset I$.
Apply the lemma to $[c1,d1]$ to obtain a maximal interval $[cm,dm]$ having the stated
properties.  Since $t \not \in S_n$ and considering $p$, we see that $cm \not \in S_n$. 
Suppose $cm > a1$.  Then we have $a \le a1 < cm \le c1 \le t < b$, so $cm \in (a,b)$. 
From the lemma, $cm \in X$, since $cm > a1 \ge 0$.  Thus, $cm \in (a,b) \cap X \subset
S_n$ ($\bot$).  Therefore, $cm \le a1$.  Likewise, $dm \ge b1$.  Thus, $f$ is a polynomial
on $J \subset [a1,b1] \subset [cm,dm]$, whence, as above, $(a,b) \cap X = \emptyset$
($\bot$).  We are at last forced to conclude that $f$ must indeed be a polynomial on $I$.

Answer (score 5):

You can also find a solution of this gem p.65, in "A primer of real functions", third edition, by R.P. Boas, Jr (which is a very nice little book...).

Comment: PP 58-59 of the 1st edition.

Comment: @smuaug: Thanks for the info. I shall check it ASAP :)

Answer (score 2):

I remember solving this in one whole week, but after a while, forgot how I did. I actually tried to remember but couldn't, so I tried this again. Spending five days, I got the solution. Compared to other solutions posted here, mine is more brute force approach. Mine has the same line of argument with the proof of Baire Category Theorem.

Problem: $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $n_x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n_x)}(x)=0$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

My solution:
Suppose $f$ is not a polynomial.

Let $A_n = \{x\in\mathbb{R}|f^{(n)}(x) = 0\}$. 
Each $A_n$ is a closed set, so it can be decomposed as $A_n=P_n\cup C_n$, where $P_n$ is perfect set, $C_n$ is at most countable. Note that $\cup_n A_n = \mathbb{R}$, and $P_n\subset P_{n+1}$ for all $n$. 
We derive a contradiction by showing that $\cap_n P_n^c$ is uncountable. (This is a contradiction since $\cap_n P_n^c\subset \cup_n C_n$).

Let $(a,b)$ be any maximal interval of a $P_n^c$(which exists since we assumed $f$ is not a polynomial). 
Then $P_{n+1}$ cannot contain intervals $(a,s)$ or $(t,b)$, otherwise, $f^{(n)}$ be constant on those intervals, and the constant should be zero, which contradicts maximality of $(a,b)$.

Thus, we have either one of two cases:

1. $P_{n+1}^c$ has at least two maximal intervals inside $(a,b)$. Call one of them by $L$, and one of the others by $R$. (let all members of $L$ be less than any members of $R$)
2. $(a,b)$ remains a maximal interval of $P_{n+1}^c$.

Let $I_{n+1}$ be 'either $L$ or $R$'  in Case 1,  '$(a,b)$' in Case 2.

We continue finding maximal interval $I_{m+1}$ of $P_{m+1}^c$ inside $I_m$ where $m\geq n$.

Considering choices of $I_m$ for $m\geq n$, and taking intersections $\cap_{m\geq n} I_m$, we can generate uncountably many members of $\cap_n P_n^c$.

Remark::
If Case 1 occurs infinitely many times, consider $LR$ sequences that both have $L$ and $R$ infinitely many times.

If Case 1 only occurs finitely many, then the interval sequence $I_m$ is stationary.

Answer (score 0):

Some have mentioned the Fabius function as one close to being a counterexample. I think the following example might be of interest. The function $f$ is almost everywhere locally a polynomial but not one itself. It is constructed similarly to the Fabius function.
Define the sequence of real-valued functions of domain $[0,1]$, $(f_n)_0^\infty$ as follows.
\begin{align}
f_0(x)&=1\\
f_{n+1}(x) &= \frac92\int_0^x u_n(t) \, dt\\
\text{where } u_n(x) &=
\begin{cases}
f_n(3x) \text{ if } 0\leq x<\frac{1}{3}\\
0\text{ if } \frac{1}{3}\leq x <\frac{2}{3}\\
-f_n(3x-2) \text{ if } \frac{2}{3}\leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. Some of its properties are the following.

- $f$ is infinitely differentiable.
- For every $x\in [0,1]\backslash\mathcal{C}$ (where $\mathcal{C}$ denotes the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)) there exists a neighborhood $(a,b)\ni x$ on which $f$ coincides with a polynomial. In fact said neighborhood is widest when $a = \max(y\in\mathcal{C}:y<x)$ and $b = \min(y\in\mathcal{C}:y>x)$. Nicely, that polynomial gets matched by all $f_n$ on $(a,b)$ when $n\geq N$, for some $N$ (depending on $x$).
- If $x\in\mathcal{C}$ and $x$ is a unilateral limit point of $\mathcal{C}$ then by continuity the derivatives of $f$ at $x$ will eventually vanish. If $x$ is a bilateral limit point of $\mathcal{C}$ then the derivatives of $f$ at $x$ are all non-zero.

So a close call. The function looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jGZP.png).