# Does there exist a supersmooth non-polynomial function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let's call a $C^{\infty}$-function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue supersmooth if whenever $a_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}f^{(n)}(x)\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere. Similarly, let's call $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Baire supersmooth if whenever $a_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}f^{(n)}(x)\rightarrow 0$ except on a meager set.

- Is every Lebesgue supersmooth function a polynomial? $\mathbf{No}$. Answered by Pietro Majer in the comments by referring to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/94038/22277).
- Is every Baire supersmooth function a polynomial? $\mathbf{No}$. Answered by Pietro Majer in the comments by referring to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/94038/22277).
- Do we get the same solutions if we replace "meager" and "measure zero" with "countable"?
- What happens in higher dimensions?

I am asking this question mainly out of curiosity and because it seems like such a function would be a good example to have in mind if one exists.

Comment: It might help that already a single $x_0$ that works for $a_n = 1$ 
suffices to make $f$ analytic, with growth no faster than $\exp|x-x_0|$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I don't think it's that obvious, because we get to choose $x$ (or a conull/comeager set of $x$) depending on the sequence $a_n$

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies: How single $x_0$ and $a_n=1$ implies that $f$ is analytic?

Comment: Sorry, it does not, at least not the way I imagined.
The Taylor series at $x_0$ converges to a function that's $O(\exp\left|x-x_0\right|)$,
but it's not obvious that this function agrees with $f(x)$ on any $x \neq x_0$.

Comment: As to the first two questions: no: see the examples here, where the exceptional set is the Cantor set http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94038/is-f-a-polynomial-provided-that-it-is-partially-smooth/94157#94157

Comment: @Joseph: a further question would be: is there a Lebesgue (resp., Baire) supersmooth function which is not locally polynomial a.e. (resp., on a residual set)?

Comment: If the $a_n$ can be arbitrary, does the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ not imply that only finitely many $f^{(n)}(x)$ are non-zero, at least at that particular value of $x$?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: it sure feels that way, if $a_n$ grows quicker than any computable function, then there is no way that $f^{(n)}(x)$ can kill this series unless it is eventually 0 as $n$ grows, (at least not any natural $f$).

Comment: @Pietro Majer. I asked the further question you suggested here http://mathoverflow.net/q/182423/22277.