# A conjecture about certain values of the Fabius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, functional-equations, conjectures

The [Fabius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) is a smooth monotone function $F:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, satisfying functional equations
$$F(0)=0, \quad F(1-x)=1-F(x)\tag1$$
and
$$F'(x) = 2 \,F(2 x) \quad \text{for} \,\, 0<x<1/2.\tag2$$

[image: Fabius graph]

The function $F$ assumes rational values at [dyadic rational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) arguments. In particular, it is known [$\!^{[1]}$](http://web.archive.org/web/20170219235751/https://www.pdf-archive.com/2017/02/20/rvachev/rvachev.pdf)[$\!^{[2]}$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07999) that
$$F\left(2^{-n}\right) = \frac1{n! \, 2^{\binom{n+1}2}} \, \sum_{m\ge0}\binom n {2m} \, c_m,\tag3$$
where $c_m$ are defined by the recurrence
$$c_0 = 1, \quad c_n = \frac1{(4^n - 1)(2n+1)} \, \sum_{m\ge1} \binom{2n+1}{2m+1} \, c_{n-m}.\tag4$$
Note that only finite number of terms in each sum are non-zero.

The values $F\left(2^{-n}\right) $ appear as [A272755](http://oeis.org/A272755) / [A272757](http://oeis.org/A272757) in the OEIS.

Let
$$a_n = F\left(2^{-n}\right) \, 2^{\binom {n-1}2}  \, (2n)! \, \prod_{m=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\left(4^m - 1\right).\tag5$$
This sequence begins
$$1, \, 5, \, 15, \, 1001, \, 5985, \, 2853675, \, 26261235, \, 72808620885, \, 915304354965 \, ...\tag6$$
*(see more terms [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/2d439ecfcc8ff23367d4a0b4a47a4a86/raw/997900be2c083bf4f87d4ab903982dc05d263b9b/gistfile1.txt))*

I conjecture that all terms of this sequence are integers. How can we prove (disprove) this conjecture?

Comment: My initial thought was to prove that your "fudge factor" used when going from $F$ to $a$ would be more than enough to make each term in the defining sum integral, but it's more delicate than that (as you probably knew). For example the $2^{-n(n+1)/2}/n!$ term when multiplied by the fudge factor is not in general an integer; there are powers of 2 in the denominator. So one has to think harder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have posted  in [arXiv:1702.05442](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442) the English translation of a paper about Fabius 
function that I published in Spanish in 1982 (we will refer to it as (A)). 
With the Theorems in this paper
the question can be answered without much difficulty. I have posted  also in 
[arXiv:1702.06487](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06487)
a new paper with the complete answer to this question.  Here we only show the main points of this proof.

I will call $R_n$ your numbers $a_n$.
First it is shown that 
$$R_{2n+1}=F_n\frac{(4n+1)!!}{(2n-1)!!}.$$
where $F_n$ are natural numbers introduced in my old paper (A).
This shows the conjecture for $R_n$  in case $n$ is an odd number.

For the other case, first prove that the numbers $R_n$ are related by the equation
$$R_n=2d_n (2n-1)!! \prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(2^{2k}-1)$$
with some   rational numbers $d_n$ introduced in (A).
These numbers $d_n$ are related to the $F_n$ so that at the end
we get 
$$R_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2 F_k}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{2k}\frac{(4n-1)!!}{(2k+1)!!}
\prod_{\ell=k+1}^n(2^{2\ell}-1)$$
This shows that the denominator of $R_{2n}$ is at most a power of $2$.

The relation between $R_n$ and $d_n$ implies that the same power will appear in 
the denominator of $2d_n$. An easy induction shows that this power is $0$.

We have other results about the values of Fabius function in  arXiv:1702.06487 
including a relation with Bernoulli numbers. This paper is a preliminary 
version.

Comment: Can you say something about the values of this function, which is somehow similar? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94038/is-f-a-polynomial-provided-that-it-is-partially-smooth/94157#94157

Comment: @Pietro Majer  Not for the moment. I am now trying to 
put in order my second arXiv paper  arXiv:1702.06487. Adding
some new material to it. Your question appear to be 
interesting. I will try.

Comment: A newer version of the paper: http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/s51/s51.pdf

Comment: A related conjecture: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283519/19661