Function whose derivatives eventually vanish almost everywhere
As a takeaway of this post we have the following result.

P. Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable such that for all $x\in[0,1]$ the sequence $\{f^{(n)}(x)\}$ is eventually $0$. Then $f$ is a polynomial.

Now take $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable and be $S$ the set of $x$ such that the sequence $\{f^{(n)}(x)\}$ is not eventually $0$.
I got interested in answering this question: which are valid $S$? How small can $S$ be?

Property. $S$ has no isolated points.

This is a consequence of P.

Property. Let $N=\{x\in[0,1]:f\text{ is not a polynomial locally at }x\}$. Then $N$ is a perfect set (possibly empty).

Observe that $S\subset N$.
I realised that $S$ could have zero measure. In this comment I explained the construction of an infinitely differentiable function whose derivatives eventually vanish except in the Cantor set. (I.e. for which $N=\text{ Cantor set }$).

Does anyone know of any research material pointed in this direction?
Has the function described above appeared in the literature before?

Thank you in advance.

As to the last question, it has appeared at least here on MO  :) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94038/is-f-a-polynomial-provided-that-it-is-partially-smooth#94157

Cool. I find it just amazing that SE's algorithm put me in contact with a previous ideator of one of my ideas.

Your idea is very nice, and as to priority, time is but an illusion ;)

So is yours ;) And I agree!
