# A differential operator analogy of certain fact in real analysis of smooth functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, differential-operators

Let $E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$.

Let $D$ be a differential operator defined on the space $\Gamma(E)$ of smooth sections of $E$. We fix a section $s\in \Gamma(E)$.

Assume that for every $x\in M$  there exist a natural number $n$ such that $D^n(s)(x)=0$.

> Does this imply that $D^k(s)=0$, for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$?
>
> **If the answer is "No", what about if we assume  that $D$ is an elliptic operator and $M$ is a compact manifold?**

The motivation for this question is the following fact  which I learned from the book of "R.P.Boas:A primer of real  functions".

https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/j.ctt5hh8x5

**Fact:** Assume that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function with the property  that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exist a natural number $n$ with $f^{(n)}(x)=0$.Then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: (A version of) the real analytic result you mention is discussed in this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial

Comment: @SamHopkins  Thanks for your comment.That is about smooth finction. Among answer one can find a reference to Boas book. I learned this result from the book of Boas when i was a master student any way the link you mentioned is about that classical theorem not about sections of vector bundles.

Comment: right, I just mention to link that in case other people were interested in learning more about the classic result you mentioned.

Comment: @SamHopkins yes I see thanks for the link.